# Signed Android app has crash when get user info Facebook SDK

Tags: android, crash, facebook-login

I just created a app, that using facebook sdk 3.0 to get user info . This's the code:

```
private void getMe()
{
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    CanBanNhanhAppActivity._fbtoken = session.getAccessToken();
    // make request to the /me API
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                Response response) {
            //ShowDialog(response.getError().toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
}
```

Early, The code works (through apk installing also deploy from eclipse).
But, recently, the app install from apk has crash when call `Request.executeBatchAsync(request);`  . Although, the app build through eclipse still work. I don't know why. I can't debug because only the app, that installed by apk, has crash.
This is Permission:

`private static final List PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList( "read_stream","email", "user_photos");`

p/s: I added debug and release hashkey on App in developer.facebook.

Comment: You can still see the logcat error even if you install it from apk so get the error and paste it here.

Comment: please give logcat error messages

Comment: I posted the logcat below. Thanks for help!